# In which DLL is the COM interface iStream defined?

Tags: java, com, istream, com4j

I'm a complete newbie to Windows and COM programming, trying to use com4j in order to call a COM object from Java.

Com4j generates Java interfaces from COM definitions  "*often found in .ocx, .dll, .exe, and/or .tlb files*" . It was easy for me to locate the .ocx file of my target COM object, but I have no clue regarding the standard interface iStream.

[Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28VS.85%29.aspx) mentions OLE32.DLL ( c:\Windows\Windows32\Ole32.dll ?) , but neither the com4j generator nor [oleviewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en) succeed in opening this file.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is defined in comsvcs.dll .

Comment: The DLL seems right. Unfortunately, com4j failed to generate interfaces from it. I'm looking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked to references Objidl.idl.  com4j might be able to process IDL files.

Alternatively you could try compiling the IDL into a TLB using MIDL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367372(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Any idea where I can find objidl.idl?

Comment: It's part of the Windows Platform SDK but if you have Visual Studio or VC++ installed, you robably have it too.  On my machine I found mulitple versions rooted at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\.